# does android has scripting system?

Tags: android, scripting

I can make batch or vbs file on windows and run.

this can automate alot of things.

for example: lunch other application, http GET query, etc

I wonder if there is **scripting system on android**

if there is, could you suggest **official resource?**

it would be nice if I can write some text(source code) to automate smartphone activity.

such as : regex the sms content and notice if it is suspected as important, monitor web page every 10 seconds to see if there is item on reasonable price, execute some application with parameter, working with android api, etc

Comment: Check out [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). I got no experience with that myself, but it might be able to do what you need and supports quite a few languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is scripting system on android

Nothing that is native to the device. Android is a consumer operating system; few consumers of Windows machines create batch files anymore.

> it would be nice if I can write some text(source code) to automate smartphone activity.

As alextsc notes, use [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). Or, use AIDE to write Android apps on your device. Or, use the standard Android development tools to write Android apps for use on your device. Or, find an app that already exists that does what you want.

However, you are going to need some amount of Android development experience for any of those tools.